Wait for Network fail: Got a static IP, now no network / internet
Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS:
I decided to splash some money at a static IP from my ISP.
It probably kicked in sometime yesterday night, because since then I've been unable to connect any Ubuntu server I have to the internet, because of a systemd error.
EDIT: While writing an edit, I managed to SSH to one server, but not another.
Info requested in the comments:
Home Device "Router" information (mildly redacted):
WAN IPv4: SOMETHING (as expected)
WAN IPv6: N/A
Primary and Secondary DNSv4: SOMETHING (as expected)
DHCP Server:
DHCP is Active
Gateway IP adress: 10.0.0.1
Lan subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
First IP adress: 10.0.0.2
Last IP adress: 10.0.0.254
1 static DHCP lease for Pihole
4 dynamic DHCP leases
No Port redirection
(There normally would be, but the device got rebooted this morning)
DNS Settings
No active DNS at this time (I want to rule out Pihole as a culprit)
Firewall:
Medium settings (recommended)
lmss@nextcloud:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:41:b8:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:36:dd:0f:d3:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 metric 600 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 84044sec preferred_lft 84044sec
    inet6 fd30:3733:3233:0:6236:ddff:fe0f:d3ea/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 866sec preferred_lft 266sec
    inet6 fe80::6236:ddff:fe0f:d3ea/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

lmss@nextcloud:~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:41:b8:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:36:dd:0f:d3:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


    lmss@nextcloud:~$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
    # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
    network:
      ethernets:
        eno1:
          dhcp4: true
      version: 2
    
    lmss@nextcloud:~$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml
    [sudo] password for lmss:
    # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
    network:
      version: 2
      wifis:
        wlp2s0:
          access-points:
            SOME-SSID:
              password: SOMETHING
          dhcp4: true
    lmss@nextcloud:~$

--
$sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service 

returns the same information on all devices I have tried - including also a fresh installation from this morning.
This photo shows the error:

Pihole on RaspberryPi OS and Windows 11 runs without incident.
Systeminformation reports a local IP has been set, but the device does not show up in my router dashboard.
Inspired by the solution at systemd-networkd-wait-online service timing out during boot I tried to run
$sudo ./lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online

Which got me nowhere. The service simply timed out.
I tried to stop and disable the service:
$sudo systemctl stop systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
$sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

Which was also a dud.
I have no idea what goes on. Anything is appreciated.
EDIT 1:
My devices are connected via a "router" to my ISP. It's a pretty basic home network setup, like most people have. They are cabled into the "router" with no other hardware between. The "router" - ahem "Home Device" - has an active firewall with factory settings.
EDIT 2: The devices boot to the extend that I end up with a stand alone-device that can't connect to the internet. I

Please share some network stats and config in your question. ip link show and the contents of your files inside /etc/netplan would be a good start.

I'm confused by your statement that your devices won't boot yet you can show us a picture of an error on a booted device. I assume you don't really mean "boot"?

@OrganicMarble Point taken. They boot to the extend that I end up with a stand alone-device that is not connected to the internet and can't be SSH'ed into.

@user1608347 OK thanks. Please add this info to your question, not in comments, since comments will vanish once supplementary info has been added.

Yeah, it's super confusing. Won't boot means you end up in black screen, emergency mode, kernel panic, etc. Not "won't connect to internet".

Ok, from your ISP provided "gateway", you should be able to see some important information, that you should include in your question, such as: 1) Confirm that you "gateway" has the static IP as outside address. 2) The DHCP settings of your gateway (since I assume this is acting as DHCP server) 3) A list of clients connected to the LAN part of your network. This is important as to how you should configure your home devices to connect to your gateway.

@ArturMeinild I'm on it!

Could you please include output of ip a also?

Ok we can see that you actually have connection, and get an IP address on your wireless adapter wlp2s0 - here you have the internal IP 10.0.0.2/24. For some reason, your gateway does not hand out an IP address on the ethernet interface. This probably doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu (since your netplan config for the ethernet looks correct), but points to a problem with the configuration on your ISP gateway device.

Now I'm going to sound like every IT department ever, but you did of course try to restart your ISP gateway? Cheap ISP gateways tend to crap up sometimes...

@ArturMeinild Proud to report that I did indeed reboot the "router" this morning +/-
Also, as I mentioned: I have no issues with my Pihole / Debian server or my Windows 11 machine

Still, your gateway not handing out an IP address on the ethernet adapter, to me indicates a problem with the DHCP server for you router (or perhaps a hardware malfunction) more than an Ubuntu problem. At least, not an Ubuntu problem I can identify.

May I suggest you try a brand new Ethernet cable, directly from one of your servers to you gateway, to see if it's perhaps a hardware malfunction? Seems most likely to me at this point.

Thanks for taking your time, @ArturMeinild !
I am suspecting it's an ISP / Home Device thing, since I'm not completely without internet access. I'll contact the ISP and open a ticket with them. They have a tendency to give me a long pause in conversation when I mention anything Linux, so good luck to me!

Re: Ethernet cables: I did try and replace both cables with new ones. I also tried different Ethernet ports on the Home Device. No such luck.

Good luck - but sorry, I can't pinpoint anything here that points to an Ubuntu problem, unfortunately.

I super appreciate you taking your time @ArturMeinild. I'll post the answer as soon as I have solved this issue. Thanks again!
